# HttpServer responds with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: java, http

I have self-hosted simple HTTP server. I tried to test with Chrome by entering address `http://localhost:8077/hello` and got error:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

How to solve this problem?

```
package com.kpv.gateway;
        
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;        

public class SimpleHttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create an HttpServer instance 
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(8077), 0);

        // Create a context for a specific path and associate it with a handler
        server.createContext("/hello", new HelloHandler());

        // Start the server
        server.start();
    }

    // Define a simple handler
    static class HelloHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            // Get the output stream to write the response
            OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
            
            System.out.print("hello");

            String htmlResponse = "<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>";
            os.write(htmlResponse.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, htmlResponse.length());`

Comment: `HttpExchange#sendResponseHeaders` - as per the documentation "This method must be called prior to calling getResponseBody().".